# Get time from DateTime Variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I am working in ruby, i ahave an object containing today's datetime from database. I only want time truncating the date. How can i get that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try [DateTime#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%H:%M")
# => "12:17"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
time1 = Time.now
puts "Current Time : " + time1.hour + ":" + time1.min + ":" + time1.sec
```

Taken from & credit to - [This TutorialsPoint Post](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm).

Comment: It should be noted that `DateTime.min` returns `0` for whole hours, not `00` as you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you use it really often you can use the gem [time_splitter](https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter) to help you set some accessors of date, time, hour and minute for your datetime attributes. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the different Rails date formats from here : [Rails Date Formats](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/)

Example :

```
time = Time.now
time.strftime("%d %B %Y")
# => 12 December 2016
```

Comment: question is get the time part from datetime.... your result is totally not related somehow.

Comment: @V-SHY Ha! They were 3 characters away from making this actually answer the question... and, sadly, they chose the wrong 3 characters.

Comment: @V-SHY My intention here is to provide information about all the formats that can be used and not just related to the time part.