# Why my time field in rails app showing the date as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've this app in rails where one of the model has an attribute of time field, but after saving the form when I'm rendering the model data then I'm seeing a default date as well.

Here's the field-

```
<%= form.label :Time%>
<%= form.time_field(:timeOfservice,  :class=>'form-control mb-2',
                                     :min=>"10:00",
                                     :max=>"20:00", 
                                     :step=>'3600',
                                     required: true,
                                     id: :appointment_timeOfservice,
                                     :autocomplete=>'off') %>
```

This is what's showing on the page

```
2000-01-01 13:00:00 UTC
```

The time is being saved perfectly for each form of that model but the date 2000-01-01 with time is showing on every form of that model.

Can anyone explain how to correct this? I only want time to show not the date.

Comment: Do you use `timestamp` field to store the result?

Comment: What versions of rails you are on? Also, can you please show the model behind this form from schema.rb?

Comment: The [tod](https://github.com/JackC/tod) gem adds a `TimeOfDay` class and comes with a [serializer](https://github.com/JackC/tod#activemodel-serializable-attribute-support) for mapping to / from SQL `time` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because Ruby and/or Rails doesn't have any data type to represent time of the day objects without the date component.

You will have to develop your own application logic to deal with the fact that the object that comes from ActiveRecord for that column is, indeed, a DateTime object (even if in the database is only stored the time of day component).

There is already a good answer for a similar question that you can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34979912/1781212

Comment: Okay I get it and I looked into the answer you provided link of. But now what to do if I only want to show the time and not the date from the database? Can you please help me in that.

Comment: @Aadityarathore you could use, for instance, the method `DateTime#strftime` to show only the time component of the date time object: `timeOfservice.strftime("%H:%M")` - more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12562981/1781212 (or give a try to the `tod` gem that was recommended in the comment above by Stefan)

Comment: You could create you own `format` or just use one of the provided ones like `:time` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_fs

Answer (score 0):

Because `Time` and `DateTime` data types are represented in `Ruby`, `Rails` and `SQL` as `integer` value in seconds from `1 January 1970 00:00:00` by UTC. This representation known as the `Unix epoch` date format.
And other time and date values are strictly saying integer values of seconds:

```
3.2.0 :001 > Time.at(60)
 => 1970-01-01 00:01:00 +0000
3.2.0 :002 > Time.at(3600)
 => 1970-01-01 01:00:00 +0000
```